# IsGestureAvailable from object outside main game class - impact of object creation location?

Tags: xna, null, initialization, windows-phone

One of my students was getting an XNA call to TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable always returning null, even though EnabledGestures was being correctly used in the game Initialize() method.

The call was being done inside an input-handling object created in the game constructor.

Just for curiosity's sake, he decided to create the input-handling object in the game Initialize() method also, rather than in the game constructor. And behold, the problem disappeared! Now IsGestureAvailable works as it should.

Does anyone know or have an idea of why this should matter? TouchPanel is a static class, so even though GraphicsDevice is created after the Game constructor but before Initialize, I can't see how the location of creation of the input-handling object should impact the result of a call to TouchPanel. Any guesses?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: Please see if these is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837747/cant-seem-to-get-touch-input-from-touchpanel-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: Personally when using XNA I never try to initialize anything self-created in the Game's Constructor.
[`Game.Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.initialize) "Override this method to query for any required services, and _load any non-graphics resources_. Use LoadContent to load graphics resources."

Comment: Subspider, Kolky, thanks, but it's not about solving: the problem was identifed and solved, as I said in the question: the object creation -- new View(); -- was being done in the constructor, and doing it in the Initialize solved it. The question is not about solving this, but at trying to understand WHY it is necessary to do this in Initialize()! After all, TouchPanel is a static class and so should be available from program launch, that is, long before both the constructor and Initialize() are called.

Comment: So the doubt is: what the heck is happening in GraphicsDevice (the only thing that runs before Initialize and after the constructor), that impacts TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable???