# TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable() is always false

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

here is the code
the debugger enters the handlinput region but never clears the touchpanel.isgestureavailable, even when we tap the screen
thanks for ur helpin advance :)

```cs
 #region Handle Input
        public override void HandleInput(InputState input)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("hey stackoverflow\n");

            if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("check presence\n");

                // read the next gesture
                var gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
                if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Tap | gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Flick | gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Hold)
                {
                // code sample
                }
            }

            base.HandleInput(input);
        }
        #endregion
```

plz help been doing this for two days now !!!!!

Comment: This has been answered in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837747/cant-seem-to-get-touch-input-from-touchpanel-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to initialize the gesture you want to handle.

`TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = gestureType;`

Comment: I've enabled the gestures using TouchPanel.EnabledGestures Property.
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Hold | GestureType.Tap |GestureType.Flick;
TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable is still 
always false.

Comment: According to the MSDN library, the only way to set it `true` is set `TouchPanel.EnabledGestures`:  

"_Before gestures can become available, they first must be set with the TouchPanel.EnabledGestures property.
If IsGestureAvailable is true, TouchPanel.ReadGesture can be used to read the gesture data._" In which method are you initializing it?